# Magento2 without cart price rule how to add a custom coupon code

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon

In to Magento 2.2.2 site.

I want to give different price coupon code to the customers.

How to create coupon code programmatically if i create cart price rule then cart price rule is many created.

Please provide me a better solution for that

Thanks in advance.